# Combine overlapping UIBezierPaths to create a single mask

Tags: ios, mask, uibezierpath

I'm looking to create a mask in my view that is shaped like several circles. Here `blurView` is the view I want to have cut outs in, and `frames` contains `CGRect` frame values for these circles/ovals.

```
let holes = UIBezierPath()
 for f in frames {
      let p = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: f)
      holes.appendPath(p)
}

 let path = UIBezierPath(rect: blurView.bounds)
 path.appendPath(holes)
 path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
 let mask = CAShapeLayer()
 mask.path = path.CGPath
 mask.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
 blurView.layer.mask = mask
```

This works quite well, except when circles overlap, the contents of the `blurView` show through instead of the view below it. How can I fix that?

Edit: Using Rob's answer, I got somewhere, but not quite where I want to be. The edges of the mask are ragged, they lack anti-aliasing:

[image: screenshot]

Any way to fix that?

Comment: Maybe you could include a screen shot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is to fill a bitmap context with an opaque colour and then clear anything we want to clip. Grab an image of that bitmap context and use as a mask.

You can copy this into a playground if you like:

```
import UIKit

// A couple of overlapping circles to play with
let frames = [
    CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200),
    CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 200)
]

let blurView = UIImageView(image: ...) // <== You can drag an image here. Literals are cool.

let size = blurView.bounds.size
let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

// First, create a bitmap context to work in.
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue)
let ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(size.width*scale), Int(size.height*scale),
8, 4 * Int(size.width * scale), CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo.rawValue)
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, scale, scale)

// iOS draws upsidedown from Core Graphics, so you'll probably want to flip your context:
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, size.height))

// Everything we want to draw should be opaque
// Everything we want to clip should be translucent

CGContextSetGrayFillColor(ctx, 1, 1) // white
CGContextFillRect(ctx, blurView.bounds)

// And now we clear all our circles
CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, .Clear)
CGContextSetGrayFillColor(ctx, 1, 0) // clear
for f in frames {
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, f)
}

// Make the masking image
let maskImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx)

// For your playground amusement (you can quicklook this line)
UIImage(CGImage: maskImage)

// Create the masking layer
let mask = CALayer()
mask.frame = blurView.layer.frame
mask.contents = maskImage

// And apply it
blurView.layer.mask = mask

// And the final so you can quicklook it
blurView
```

[image]

Comment: I was afraid it would be something like this. Curiously enough, I was going to make a "this is what I get" and "this is what I want" demos in photoshop, but was not able to imitate the "this is what I get" part (granted, I'm not a pro in photoshop), it just merges things into what I want so easily. Totally backwards compared to iOS. :)

Comment: Thanks for help, this is definitely getting somewhere. There were a couple of problems with this code though. One is it was not looking so good on retina - but this was easy enough to fix. The other is that the edges of the mask seem too sharp, there is no anti-aliasing to the circles. Is there a way to add that in?

Comment: See the docs for `CALayer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing` as a start. I don't know if you can apply antialiasing to masks, however.

Comment: Rob, I took the liberty of editing your answer with the solution I cooked up based on it. Instead of creating a black and white image and turning it into an opaque/transparent mask, I created an image with an alpha channel right away. This allows the native drawing functions to take care of antialiasing.

Comment: If that's working well, that's great. Some of the mask functions require an image in the Gray colorspace (but I don't believe the ones used here).